# symfony2 error: /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache' (include_path='.:/opt/lampp/lib/php')

Tags: symfony, console, centos6, include-path

I have a problem this morning with my symfony project.
I develop an application online sales that works without problem on my pc running on a ubuntu system.
I 'bought a dedicated server (centos) in which I wanted to put my application.
so I transferred all my project in the FTP serveur.mais qd I want to accede to the site with mozilla I get this error

Warning: require_once (/opt/lampp/htdocs Symfony/web/.. /app/bootstrap.php.cache..): Failed to open stream: No such file or folder of this type in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/web/app.php on line 6

Fatal error: require_once (): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/web/../app/bootstrap.php.cache..' (Include_path = ':/opt/lampp/lib/php.') In / opt / lampp / htdocs / Symfony / web / app.php on line 6

and when I do php app / console in the terminal told me Could not open input file: app / console

[root @ server Symfony] # sudo php app / console cache: clear - env = prod
Could not open input file: app / console
[root @ server Symfony] # php app / console
Could not open input file: app / console

please  i need help

Comment: thank you for answer but when i do app/console cache:clear -env=prod like you say to me i have this error                         [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                                                                 
  Cannot import resource "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/src/Izabel/BoutiqueBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml" from "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/a  
  pp/config/routing.yml". (The YAML value does not appear to be valid UTF-8.)

Answer (score 1):

do a :

```
composer update
```

and eventually an :

```
app/console cache:clear -env=prod
```

not

```
app / console cache: clear - env = prod
```

Comment: thank you for answer but when i do app/console cache:clear -env=prod like you say to me i have this error [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException] Cannot import resource "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/src/Izabel/BoutiqueBundle/Resources/config/routing.ym‌​l" from "/opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/a pp/config/routing.yml". (The YAML value does not appear to be valid UTF-8.)

Comment: I think that you have a problem with you text editor or IDE that is not configured to format files as UTF-8.
Got see your preferences and try to find out if you can force your editor to use utf-8.
This can be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic but i want to help.

You can save your document with utf-8 encoding option.

If you are on windows use Notepad++.

```
Encoding > Encode in UTF-8
```

If you are mac or linux use SublimeText2.

```
File > Save With Encoding > UTF-8
```